# Creating method to use one foreach instead multiple

Tags: c#

I'm working with C#, and I have working code where I repeated same code every line, and that's because I'm creating list, conversions, extracting data, etc.

I have multiple `foreach` clauses, multiple `lists`, multiple conversions of `list` to `datatables`. My question is, what can I do to refactor this in order to have clean code?

```
 private void BtnLoadReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new SQLDataMgr();

            List<string> DesignStatusList = new List<string>();
            List<string> ShopStatusList = new List<string>();
            List<string> CustomerTypeList = new List<string>();
            List<string> CustomerList = new List<string>();
            List<string> ResellerList = new List<string>();
            List<string> StateList = new List<string>();
            List<string> ProjectManagerList = new List<string>();
            List<string> SalesRepresentativeList = new List<string>();


            var checkedDesignStatus = cboDesignStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedShopStatus = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedCustomerType = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedCustomer = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedReseller = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedState = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedProjectManager = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
            var checkedSalesRepresentative = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);

            foreach (var i in checkedDesignStatus)
            {
                DesignStatusList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            foreach (var i in checkedShopStatus)
            {
                ShopStatusList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            foreach (var i in checkedCustomerType)
            {
                CustomerTypeList.Add(i.Text);
            }

            foreach (var i in checkedCustomer)
            {
                CustomerList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            foreach (var i in checkedReseller)
            {
                ResellerList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            foreach (var i in checkedState)
            {
                StateList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            foreach (var i in checkedProjectManager)
            {
                ProjectManagerList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            foreach (var i in checkedSalesRepresentative)
            {
                SalesRepresentativeList.Add(i.Text);
            }
            DataTable designStatusParameters = ToStringDataTable(DesignStatusList);
            DataTable shopStatusParameters = ToStringDataTable(ShopStatusList);
            DataTable customerTypeParameters = ToStringDataTable(CustomerTypeList);
            DataTable customerParameters = ToStringDataTable(CustomerList);
            DataTable resellerParameters = ToStringDataTable(ResellerList);
            DataTable stateParameters = ToStringDataTable(StateList);
            DataTable projectManagerParameters = ToStringDataTable(ProjectManagerList);
            DataTable salesRepresentativerParameters = ToStringDataTable(SalesRepresentativeList);


        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please tell us, what does this code accomplish? Also make that the title of the question — see [ask]. Furthermore, you should ensure that you include enough context so that we can make sense of this code and give you good advice.

Comment: (Please specify in every code you create what it is to accomplish, using the best mechanisms provided by the language or development environment of choice.)

Answer (score 3):

First step is to look at the repeated code then copy an single into a method.
In this case a could method name would seem to be `CreateDataTable`.

What are the commonalities?

- A `ComboBox` that has checked items.
- Get an `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` depending on which is returned by the where clause
- Creates a list of the text value from each checked item
- Creates a `DataTable` using `ToStringDataTable(parameters`

Since the type in and type out is all the same, this makes it much easier to refactor out into a method. The question then is what input and what output?

Input = `ComboBox`, output = `DataTable'. This give the method signature needed:

```
DataTable CreateDataTable(ComboBox cbo) {
}
```

Now put in those lines that are repeated and change the `*Status` to `cbo` and instead of assigning the `DataTable` just `return` the result of `ToStringDataTable(parameters)`.

```
DataTable CreateDataTable(ComboBox cbo) {

    var checkedItems = cbo.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
    List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var i in checkedItms) {
        parameter.Add(i.Text);
    }

    return ToStringDataTable(parameters);
}
```

Now clean up the original method:

```
public class Refactor {
  private void BtnLoadReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var db = new SQLDataMgr();

        var designStatusParameters = CreateDataTable(cboDesignStatus);
        var shopStatusParameters = CreateDataTable(cboShopStatus);
        var customerTypeParameters = CreateDataTable(cboCustomerType);
        var customerParameters = CreateDataTable(cboCustomer);
        var resellerParameters = CreateDataTable(cboReseller);
        var stateParameters = CreateDataTable(cboState);
        var projectManagerParameters = CreateDataTable(cboProjectManager);
        var salesRepresentativeParameters = CreateDataTable(cboSalesRepresentative);
        //Rest of the method
    }   
}
```

This could be further improved by using some additional LINQ chains if the items returned by the where clause supports them.

Example:

```
List<String> parameters = cbo.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

which would simplifying the method even further:

```
DataTable CreateDataTable(ComboBox cbo) {

    List<string> parameterList = List<String> parameters = cbo.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

    return ToStringDataTable(parameters);
}
```